# How to set cookies in laravel 5 independently inside controller

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

I want to set cookies in Laravel 5 independently

i.e., Don't want to use

`return response($content)->withCookie(cookie('name', 'value'));`

I just want to set cookie in some page and retrieve in some other page

Creation can be like this

`$cookie = Cookie::make('name', 'value', 60);`

But how can i retrieve those cookies in some controller itself ?

Comment: Hi @user4989228 please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670571/laravel-set-cookie-not-working/49685759#49685759 i'm use easily set and get cookie. Thanks

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Cookie::queue($name, $value, $minutes);
```

This will queue the cookie to use it later and later it will be added with the response when response is ready to be sent. You may [check the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#cookies) on `Laravel` website.

Update (`Retrieving A Cookie Value`):

```
$value = Cookie::get('name');
```

---

*Note: If you set a cookie in the current request then you'll be able to retrieve it on the next subsequent request.*

Comment: Please check the documentation (link given in the answer), you'll find everything there.

Comment: He asked for Laravel 5. This example is for Laravel4.

Comment: Doesn't work on my Laravel 5. That `Cookie` class seems to be gone.

Comment: @DanJones, I'll check soon, which release (5.0/5.2/5.2...) of version - 5 you are on?

Comment: 5.0.35
Although, I'm still pretty new to Laravel, so there may be something I'm missing.

Comment: I'm getting "maximum execution time exceeded" when using this.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to set cookie and get it outside of request, Laravel is not your friend.

Laravel cookies are part of Request, so if you want to do this outside of Request object, use good 'ole PHP setcookie(..) and $_COOKIE to get it.

Comment: `setcookie()` is not working, are there any settings that may be interfering this?

Answer (score 1):

You are going right way my friend.Now if you want retrive `cookie` anywhere in project just put this code `$val = Cookie::get('COOKIE_NAME');`
That's it!
[For more information how can this done click here](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/49/retrieving-a-cookie-from-the-request)

Comment: Hi, I use $value=Cookie::get('name'); but when I echo $value it shows me blank, before this I set cookie by using Cookie::queue('name',$name);
Plz help me to resolve this

Comment: $value will be null if cookie not present. see this link: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/49/retrieving-a-cookie-from-the-request

Comment: @Jigs Virani You are wrong. If you want to set cookie and get it in Laravel outside of request, Laravel is not your friend. Even link you gave says; "This is basically the same as Request::cookie()". So, Nil is right to complain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code with explanation.

```
 //Create a response instance
 $response = new Illuminate\Http\Response('Hello World');

 //Call the withCookie() method with the response method
 $response->withCookie(cookie('name', 'value', $minutes));

 //return the response
 return $response;
```

Cookie can be set forever by using the forever method as shown in the below code.

```
$response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('name', 'value'));
```

## Retrieving a Cookie

```
//’name’ is the name of the cookie to retrieve the value of
$value = $request->cookie('name');
```