# Working with Laravel 5.3 cookies

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I'm trying to create a cookie in my application registration method, using laravel class `Cookie`, but when I try to retrieve it in another controller method I get a `null` value.

Here is how I created it:

`$cookie = Cookie::make('user_data', $user_data, 43800);`

In that method, if I print it, it gives me the correct value, but after registration, if the user goes back to the registration URL, I need to check if the cookie exists, but it is giving me null when I print it.

`dd(Cookie::get('user_data'));`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I got it to work, the thing is, you need to attach the created cookie to your response in order to attach it to the client, if you don't return it with the response, it won't work, here's how I did it:

`return redirect()->route('v3.autoevaluacion')->cookie($cookie);`

Comment: Or you can use the `queue` method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516762/how-to-set-cookies-in-laravel-5-independently-inside-controller