# I need to create Cookie and retrieve its information in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, cookies, laravel-9

I create the cookie but I can't retrieve it

```
web.blade.php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

Route::get('/cookie/', function () {
   return Cookie::make('codigo', 1, 60);
   //Result
   //code_id=1; expires=Fri, 20-Jan-2023 14:40:56 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax
}
Route::get('/retornar/', function () {
   //1º recovery test
   return Cookie::get('code_id');

   //2º recovery test
   if (Cookie::has('code_id')) {
       $cookieValue = Cookie::get('code_id');
       return response()->json($cookieValue);
   }
   return response()->json('Cookie not exists');

   //3º recovery test
   return dd( Cookie::get('codigo') );

   //For all results, it is always null
   //NULL
}


I already changed it here, and I don't have a result
app\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php
protected $except = [
   'code_id'
];
```

I used these examples:
• [https://phpforever.com/laravelexample/laravel-set-get-delete-cookies/#:~:text=We%20can%20use%20cookies%3A%3A,('name'%2C%20'value')%3B](https://phpforever.com/laravelexample/laravel-set-get-delete-cookies/#:%7E:text=We%20can%20use%20cookies%3A%3A,(%27name%27%2C%20%27value%27)%3B)
• https://satellasoft.com/artigo/php/manipulando-cookies-no-laravel
• https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Cookie/QueueingFactory.html#method_forever
• https://onlinewebtutorblog.com/laravel-9-cookies-get-set-delete-cookie-example/

Comment: This answer need for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685759/7372534

Comment: you make codigo , but inside middleware you set as code_id , also in the 1st result there is no codigo , is this correct ?

Answer (score 2):

To create a cookie, you can use the make method on the Cookie facade. The first argument is the name of the cookie, and the second argument is the value. You can also pass an optional third argument, which is the number of minutes the cookie should last before expiring.

```
Cookie::make('name', 'value', $minutes);
```

To send the cookie to the browser, you can attach it to a response object. You can do this using the withCookie method on a response object.

```
return response('Hello World')->withCookie(Cookie::make('name', 'value', $minutes));
```

To retrieve the value of a cookie, you can use the get method on the Cookie facade. The first argument is the name of the cookie.

```
$value = Cookie::get('name');
```

You can also check if a cookie exists by using the has method on the Cookie facade. The first argument is the name of the cookie.

```
if (Cookie::has('name')) {
    // do something
}
```