# How to Store array into cookie in laravel 5.6 and get in controller without going to view page?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5.6, setcookie

I have below the array.

```
$data = array(
  'category'=>array(
     '0'=>1,
     '1'=>15,
     '2'=>7,
     '3'=>76,
   )
)
```

How do i store above array into cookie in laravel 5.6 ? and how to retrive all cookies value from cookie?

Comment: I have read laravel 5.6 cookie doc. but i never found how to store a cookie in laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#cookies

Comment: maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516762/how-to-set-cookies-in-laravel-5-independently-inside-controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store array cookie in laravel 5.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872142/how-to-store-array-cookie-in-laravel-5-4)

Answer (score 4):

You need to serialize array with **json_encode** or **serialize** functions and store it with Cookie facade.

```
Cookie::queue('cookie_name', json_encode($data), $cookieTime);
```

or

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('cookie_name', json_encode($data), $cookieTime));
```

Comment: why you used queue?

Comment: Because there are 2 ways to attach cookies in laravel (except default php setcookie): cookie method on response (response()->cookie) or use Cookie::queue method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
  'category'=>array(
     '0'=>1,
     '1'=>15,
     '2'=>7,
     '3'=>76,
   )
);

// to store
$json = serialize($data); // convert to string

cookie('name', $json, $minutes);

// to retrive

$value = Cookie::get('name');
```

Comment: Please add some explanations to your answer.

Comment: I would avoid using `serialize` for arrays. It's not necessary. Use json encoding instead. Serialize can be a potential security risk

Answer (score 0):

```
setCookieArray( $arr, $cookie, $minutes ) {
    $json = serialize( $arr );
    if( strlen( $json ) > 4096 ){
        foreach( $arr as $key => $val ){
            if( is_array( $val ))
              setCookieArray( $val, $cookie .'_a_'. $key, $minutes )
            else
              cookie( $cookie .'_v_'. $key, $val, $minutes);
        }
    } else {
      cookie('name', $json, $minutes);
    }
}

setCookieArray( array(
  'category'=>array(
     '0'=>1,
     '1'=>15,
     '2'=>7,
     '3'=>76,
  )
), 'mycookie', 10);
```